# Scale SVG Proportionatly to PNG

Tags: command, inkscape

I need to scale some svg's proportionately and output to a PNG max size 32px (either dimension).

Right now I'm using Inkscape but the proportions get warped depending on the image.

```
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" "yo.svg" --export-png="yo.png" --export-area-drawing -w32 -h32
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know Windows batch scripts, but the command

```
inkscape yo.svg --query-width
inkskape yo.svg --query-height
```

will give you the width and height of your drawing. Can you use an if statement to see which one is bigger and scale only the appropriate dimension?

So if the width was greater than the height, doing:

```
inkscape yo.svg --export-png="yo.png" --export-area-drawing -w32
```

would achieve what you want.